# MySQL multi-table join with nulls

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables:

```
Codes
Code  key1   key2
1     a      hh
2     a   
3     a   
4     a   


Orders
key1   key2  val1
a      aa    foo
h      hh    bar
```

And I'd like to get

```
Desired output
code   key1   key2  val1
1      a      hh    bar 
2      a
3      a
4      a
```

I've tried it with the inner join on orders:

```
select 
      ordersa.key2, 
      code, 
      ordersb.date
   from 
      order ordersa
         right join codes
            on codes.key1 = orders.key1
         inner join orders ordersb
            on codes.key2 = ordersb.key2
```

But that takes out all the null data in key2 column and I get:

```
code   key1   key2   val1
1      a      hh     bar
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve that?

Comment: Do you not have primary keys on the two tables?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  c.Code,
  c.key1,
  IFNULL(c.key2, '') key2,
  IFNULL(o.val1, '') val1,
FROM Codes c
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.key2 = o.key2
```

Comment: `ISNULL` does not seem to be needed.

Comment: his desired output does not say he wants NULL values returned, so i replaced NULL with an empty string

Comment: Well I guess he just meant he was missing records in the output (those that were eliminated by the join). +1 Anyway.

Comment: that form of `isnull` doesn't seem to work in MySQL, "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'"

Comment: @emd sorry i am used to SQL Server, try IFNULL() instead

Comment: Here's what I did, this only returns one row, not 10: https://pastebin.com/4LPRRzep

Comment: And here's what I ended up with, but I'm sure it can be simplified or optimized: https://pastebin.com/Cn1qL9bS

Comment: there are three tables there, but you only provided two in your question. also your query does not look like the one i gave. the LEFT JOIN is very important here because it will get all results from the left table and only matched records in the right table. you are doing an INNER JOIN that is only returning records that match in both tables

Comment: Ya I tried to simplify it. In my example, I do show 2 joins though, that's the bit that changes it from 10 rows to 1.

Comment: happy to share the full schema's if that help. Appreciate your time.

Comment: no problem. sorry i don't have time to look at another question. try posting a new question :)